# How to add image as the background to rounded corners in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, liferay, liferay-theme

I have included the jQuery round corner plugin for rounded corner functionality for my theme, for first theme it is working fine because I have not added any background image to theme. When I go for second theme I have added image as background, when I try to apply round corner functionality for the theme, it is adding some background color to the corners like this https://forum.jquery.com/topic/rounded-corners-plugin-jquer-corners-js-ie-problem

I have searched every where i have not found any solution regarding this. I even tried to add background image to #navigation li and #navigation a. but it is not working in IE8, for IE8 purpose I used jQuery round corner plugin, because css3pie is not working.

```
var jq=$.noConflict();
jq(document).ready(function(){
    alert('hello alert1 ');
    jq('#navigation li').attr("data-corner","right 20px");
    jq('#navigation a').attr("data-corner","right 20px");
    jq('#navigation li').corner();
    jq('#navigation a').corner();
    jq('#subMenu li').corner();
    alert('hello alert3 ');
});
```

I have to add image for corner color(cc) in http://malsup.github.io/jquery.corner.js. Can anyone help me?

Comment: stop supporting browsers which wont support `border-radius`

Answer (score 1):

A much easier solution would be to use `border-radius`.

For example,

```
<div id='navigation'></div>
```

would be your html, and then your CSS would look something like this..

```
#navigation{
    border-radius:10px;
}
```

No JavaScript required and much faster than using jQuery.
If you're worried about browsers which do not support the border-radius property, you can use http://css3pie.com

Comment: in IE8 border-radius property wont work because it is a css3 property , that is why i go for rounded corner plugin in jquery.

Comment: Using http://css3pie.com makes the border-radius property work in IE versions 6 to 8, and is quicker and easier to use than the jQuery plugin.

Comment: i have tried css3pie also but iam using liferay theme, it is not working in liferay themes

Comment: You can include it within liferay theme, dont worry

Comment: @DanieleBaggio how to include it with liferay theme... please could you provide any link for reference

Comment: See this https://www.liferay.com/it/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/18576894